# Regex match but re.match() doesn't return anything

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I try to parse a .md file using a specific pattern with regex in python. The file is written like this:

```
## title
## title 2

### first paragraph
[lines]
...

### second
[lines]
...

## third 
[lines]
...

## last
[lines]
...
```

So i used this regular expression to match it:

```regex
##(.*)\n+##(.*)\n+###((\n|.)*)###((\n|.)*)##((\n|.)*)##((\n|.)*)
```

when I am trying it online, the regex match: 
https://regex101.com/r/8iYBrp/1

But when I am using it in python, it doesn't work, I can't understand why.

Here is my code:

Here is my code:

```py
import re

str = (
    r'##(.*)\n+##(.*)\n+###((\n|.)*)###((\n|.)*)##((\n|.)*)##((\n|.)*)')
file_regexp = re.compile(str)

## Retrieve the content of the file (I am sure this part 
## returns what I want)

m = file_regexp.match(fileContent)

# m is always None
```

I already tried to add flags, like re.DOTALL, re.I, re.M, re.S. But when I do this, the script becomes really slow and my computer starts making strange noise.

Does anyone know what I did wrong ? Any help appreciated

Comment: What's with `str = (...)` (you're shadowing builtin *str*), and also what's *featureStr*?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited my post for featureStr, just a mistake. 
I kept brackets because it was easier to understand de regex if I had to write it on several lines. (without using \ between each line)

Comment: How do you get the file contents? Is the file UTF8 encoded? Is there any BOM in it? `re.search looks for matches anywhere inside a string, `re.match` will only look for a match at the start of the string, so BOM may stop the regex from matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you assign your regex pattern to a variable str (overrides built-in `str`), but you use `featureStr` afterwards. Your resulting match object is empty, because you told it to ignore, what it matched. You can assign names to the regex placeholder using `?P<name>` and access them later. Here is a working example:

```
import re

featureStr = (
    r'##(?P<title>.*)\n+##(?P<title_2>.*)\n+###(?P<first>(.*)###(?P<second>(.*)##(?P<third>(.*)##(.*)')
file_regexp = re.compile(featureStr, re.S)

fileContent = open("markdown.md").read()

m = file_regexp.match(fileContent)

print(m.groupdict())
```

Which prints:

```
{'title': ' title', 'title_2': ' title 2', 'first': ' first paragraph\n[lines]\n...\n\n', 'second': ' second\n[lines]\n...\n\n', 'third': ' third \n[lines]\n...\n\n'}
```

I hope this helps you. Let me know if there are any questions left. Have a nice day!

Comment: Never use `(\n|.)*`, it is a very misfortunate pattern that is likely to cause a huge slowdown or crash. Use `.*` and compile with `re.S` or `re.DOTALL`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I just wanted to copy his answer and modify it for him, so that it's easier to understand, what's going on and what has changed. Anyway, thanks for the comment!

Comment: But that is an extremely bad practice to use `(.|\n)*`, it will lead to problems and further (duplicate) questions on SO. Please fix this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, (and for regex placeholder I didn't know about btw) I tried your code, but the problem remain the same, the regex doesn't match the filecontent. (so m is still None)

Comment: Did you try `m.groupdict()` as used in my answer? Are you pretty sure, your markdown is valid? Are you sure, you read your markdown correctly? I simply copied your markdown sample into a markdown file and executed the provided code and got the provided answer.

Comment: Yes ! Thw to you and Wiktor the solution was to remove ```(\n|.)*```, that expression obviously didn't pass the compilation...

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you're interested only in the lines you could just skip the lines starting with #. This could be solved with something like

```
with open("/path/to/your/file",'r') as in_file:
   for line in in_file:
       if line.startswith('#'):
          continue
       else:
          do something here.
```

Why do you need a regex?

Comment: I need to process the text in blocks, not lines. The content I have marked here with [lines]... must be retrieved in a single string

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

```
str = (r'##(.*?)\n##(.*?)\n+###(.*?)\n+###(.*?)\n+##(.*?)\n+##(.*?)')
file_regexp = re.compile(str, re.S)

fileContent = '''
## title
## title 2

### first paragraph
[lines]
...

### second
[lines]
...

## third 
[lines]
...

## last
[lines]
...
'''

m = file_regexp.search(fileContent)
print(m.groups())
```

**Output:**

```
(' title', ' title 2', ' first paragraph\n[lines]\n...', ' second\n[lines]\n...', ' third \n[lines]\n...', '')
```